# Оценка сложности алгоритма и оптимизация

Tags: python, алгоритм, list, список

Имеется список сайтов.

**Задача:**

Если в списке есть домен второго уровня, напирмер, 2o7.net, то поддомены 012.2o7.net, www.2o7.net, blog.test.2o7.net и test.2o7.net должны быть из него вообще удалены.

Если в списке есть домен третьего уровня, напирмер server.2o8.com, то поддомены 1.server.2o8.com, 2.server.2o8.com, 3.server.2o8.com, test.1.server.2o8.com и 4.server.2o8.com должны быть из него вообще удалены.

И так далее по возрастающей и незаисимо от количества поддоменов в строке.

**Как я решал:**
Сначала я отсортировал по возрастанию по количество доменов, с помощью sorted().
Не знаю какая у него сложность, так на Python не пишу, и не знаю, на основе какого алгоритма сортировки она построена, но в любом случае, сортировку можно достичь со сложность O(N * log N)

Затем обрабатывает каждый элемент отсортированного списка.
Если количество доменов равен 2, то добавляем его в cache (для дальнейшего сравнения), а также выводим в файл success.

Иначе в цикле, состоящих из возможных вариантов доменов, начиная от 2, проверял его на наличие в cache, если он там присутствует, то на удаление.
Если пройдя цикл, элемент не был удален, то добавляем его в cache и выводим в success.

Вот с этой этой части у меня проблема.

N - проход по всем элементам

K = количеству доменов - 2

В этом случае сложность этой части O(N * K)

И суммарная: N * Log N + N * K. 
Как вот эту часть оценить? Думаю N * Log N > N * K, так как количество доменов не такое большое, а количество элементов может быть больше.

Следовательно общая сложность будет равна O (N * log N)

Код:

```
import time
input_filename = "hosts.txt"
input_filename_test = "hosts_test.txt"
output_filename_success = "success.txt"
output_filename_delete = "delete.txt"

cache = {}



def load_file(input_filename):
    items = []
    start_time = time.time()
    print("Чтение файла")
    with open(input_filename, "r") as file:
        content = file.read().split("\n")
        for cont in content:
            if(cont.strip() != ""):
                items.append(cont)
    print("Чтение завершено. Время выполнения", time.time() - start_time, "c")
    return items

def sorted_list(items):
    start_time = time.time()
    print("Сортировка")
    sorted_item = sorted(items, key=lambda x: len(x.split(".")))
    print("Сортировка завершена. Время выполнения", time.time() - start_time, "c")
    return sorted_item

def get_cache(item):
    try:
        current_item = cache[item]
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(item, "не найден в cache")
        return False

def get_join(items):
    return '.'.join(items)

def processing_all(items):
    print("Обработка списка")
    start_time = time.time()
    for item in items:
        processing(item)
    print("Обработка завершена. Время выполнения", time.time() - start_time, "c")


def processing(item):
    print("Обработка ", item)

    blocks = item.split(".")
    if(len(blocks) == 2):
        save(item, output_filename_success)
        cache[item] = item
    else:
        #Проход по возможным вариациям
        for index in range(len(blocks) - 1).__reversed__():
            print(get_join(blocks[index:]))
            if(get_cache(get_join(blocks[index:]))):
                #Удаляем
                save(item, output_filename_delete)
                print(item, "Удален")
                return
            else:
                continue

        #Если не удалили, значит добавляем в cache
        save(item, output_filename_success)
        cache[item] = item


def save(item, filename):
    with open(filename, "a") as file:
        file.write(item + "\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    items = load_file(input_filename)
    items = sorted_list(items)
    processing_all(items)
а
```

Как думаете правильно оценил? И есть ли более лучший алгоритм по сложности?

Comment: Какой должен быть выходной список если на входе такой список: `["2o8.com", "1.server.2o8.com"]` ?

Comment: @MaxU 2o8.com в success и 1.server.2o8.com в delete

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
def is_subdomain(url, known_domains):
    tup = tuple(url.split("."))
    for i in range(len(tup)-1):
        if tup[i:] in known_domains:
            return True
    return False

items = [
  "2o7.net", "012.2o7.net", "www.2o7.net", "blog.test.2o7.net", "test.2o7.net",
  "server.2o8.com", "1.server.2o8.com", "2.server.2o8.com", "3.server.2o8.com", 
  "test.1.server.2o8.com", "4.server.2o8.com",
  "aaa.bbb.com", "user.blog.test.aaa.bbb.com"
]

seen = set()
selected = []
deleted = []

for x in sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.count(".")):
    if not is_subdomain(x, seen):
        selected.append(x)
    else:
        deleted.append(x)
    seen.add(tuple(x.split(".")))
```

**Сложность**: `max(O(n * log(n)), O(n * m))`, где `m` - максимальное число слов в URL минус 2.
Т.е. если максимальное число слов в хостах - 6 (пример: `user.blog.test.aaa.bbb.com`), то сложность будет `max(O(n * log(n)), O(n * 4))`.

Таким образом если `log(n) > m`, то сложность будет `O(n * log(n))`, в противном случае: `O(n * m)`

PS не уверен что правильно посчитал сложность алгоритма...

---

результат:

```
In [55]: selected
Out[55]: ['2o7.net', 'server.2o8.com', 'aaa.bbb.com']

In [56]: deleted
Out[56]:
['012.2o7.net',
 'www.2o7.net',
 'test.2o7.net',
 'blog.test.2o7.net',
 '1.server.2o8.com',
 '2.server.2o8.com',
 '3.server.2o8.com',
 '4.server.2o8.com',
 'test.1.server.2o8.com',
 'user.blog.test.aaa.bbb.com']

In [57]: seen
Out[57]:
{('012', '2o7', 'net'),
 ('1', 'server', '2o8', 'com'),
 ('2', 'server', '2o8', 'com'),
 ('2o7', 'net'),
 ('3', 'server', '2o8', 'com'),
 ('4', 'server', '2o8', 'com'),
 ('aaa', 'bbb', 'com'),
 ('blog', 'test', '2o7', 'net'),
 ('server', '2o8', 'com'),
 ('test', '1', 'server', '2o8', 'com'),
 ('test', '2o7', 'net'),
 ('user', 'blog', 'test', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'com'),
 ('www', '2o7', 'net')}
```

Comment: компактно, но сложность же у него такая же, но какая?

Comment: @danilshik, дополнил ответ. PS лучше всего сравнить время выполнения разных версий - скорость будет зависеть не только от сложности алгоритма, но и от реализации тоже)

Comment: а если сделать словарь ? или в питоне не работает, как в php, что обращение по индексу линейно в отличие от поиска в списке?

Comment: @splash58, я для этого использовал `set` - сложность поиска по `set` - `O(1)`

Comment: вот это я не знал, спс

Comment: @splash58, https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity